# Why do I not see the drop indicator in a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qt5.6

I use drag and drop in my `QTableView` (works). However, I do not see any drop indicator. I should see a line where the drop is supposed to be inserted, shouldn't I? At least [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5510887/356726) they say so.

My init is pretty much standard.

```
    // see model for implementing logic of drag
    this->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(allowDrop);
    this->setDragEnabled(allowDrag);
    this->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    this->m_model->allowDrop(allowDrop);
```

I have no idea why I do not see the indicator. A style sheet is used with the views, could that be the reason. However, I have disabled the stylesheet and still do not see it.

The view uses entire rows for selection, not sure if this causes an issue. So any hint is appreciated.

-- Edit --

As of the comment below, tried all selection modes: single, multi or extended, no visual effect. Also tried cell instead of row selection, again no improvement.

-- Edit 2 --

Currently evaluating [another style proxy example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611137/356726), similar to the one below, originally referenced [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/40881/solved-qtableview-drop-indicator-appearance/4)

-- Related --

[QTreeView draw drop indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7596584/356726)
[How to highlight the entire row on mouse hover in QTableWidget: Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23111075/356726)
https://forum.qt.io/topic/12794/mousehover-entire-row-selection-in-qtableview/7
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23111484/356726

Comment: Unclear of the context but: it has to do with selection mode as well. What is the setting?  E.g. tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);

Comment: tried all 3 modes: single, multi, extended - no effect

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, I tried two options which both worked for me. IIRC, the help came from an answer on SO.

- if you are subclassing `QTreeView`, you can override its [paintEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#paintEvent) method. It is calling by default the [drawTree()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#drawTree) method and the `paintDropIndicator()` one (the latter being part of `QAbstractItemView` private class).

You can call `drawTree()` from your `paintEvent()`, and it should override the default drag and drop indicator as well :

```
class MyTreeView : public QTreeView
{
public:
    explicit MyTreeView(QWidget* parent = 0) : QTreeView(parent) {}

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
    {
        QPainter painter(viewport());
        drawTree(&painter, event->region());
    }
};
```

- the other method is to subclass [QProxyStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) and overriding the [drawPrimitive()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#drawPrimitive) method. When you get the *element* `QStyle::PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop` as a parameter, you can paint it your own way.

The code will look like this:

```
class MyOwnStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    MyOwnStyle(QStyle* style = 0) : QProxyStyle(style) {}

    void drawPrimitive(PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption* option, QPainter* painter, const QWidget* widget) const
    {
        if (element == QStyle::PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop)
        {
            //custom paint here, you can do nothing as well
            QColor c(Qt::white);
            QPen pen(c);
            pen.setWidth(1);

            painter->setPen(pen);
            if (!option->rect.isNull())
                painter->drawLine(option->rect.topLeft(), option->rect.topRight());
        }
        else
        {
            // the default style is applied
            QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried it, I have used the QProxyStyleApproach . I see the draw line part being called, but see no visual impact in my very case. Just looks like before. Will try some of the other virtual implementations doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html#QProxyStyle The rect passed seems to always have 0x0 size.

Comment: Here https://forum.qt.io/topic/62496/is-it-possible-for-a-qtableview-to-accept-a-drop-in-the-empty-area-below-its-last-row they discuss the same approach (`QProxyStyle`), but it seems NOT to to be applicable for `QTableView`